# Regex for matching/extracting part of filename

Tags: regex

The following regex

```
var re = /(?<=_)\d*/g
```

extracts the bitrate from filenames that follow a naming convention like filename_bitrate.ext

It works for most filenames -

```
asdfasd_400.mp4
asdfasd_600.mp3
asdfasd_1000.mxf
```

Some files follow the same convention but my regex can't parse them. Ex -

```
BLIVE_CEOFoC_210720_1245_400.mp4
```

I want to basically extract the number before the .ext. How do I modify my regex to work with any filename?

Comment: Does this need to use regex? If you can use split it's more readable and equally effective

Comment: That is a pretty unreliable way to get the bitrate. You might want to look at [tag:ffmpeg], examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43263575/3124333) and [here](https://superuser.com/q/1106343/1095685).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<=_)\d+(?=\.\w+$)
(?<=_)\d+(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wLFiAN/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=_)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with a `_`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=\.\w+$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with a dot and one or more word chars till the end of string. If you use the second version with `[^.]+`, it will match any one or more chars other than a dot (so, allowing any chars in the extension).